# Rode Boom pole enquiry

Tags: boom-pole

Hi guys

I'm planning on purchasing one of the rode boom poles, either the mini or the micro.

The problem is that the micro is only £39.99 whereas the mini is closer to £70.
The only difference between them is the length of the micro is 2m and the mini is 2.05m.

Does anyone have any experience with these boom poles. I can't understand why there is such a vast price difference if the length difference is 0.5 m.

Cheers

Comment: +1; In exactly the same boat here, will be interested to see people's responses.

Answer (score 1):

Compare the weight of those two. There might be a price difference that represents materials from which both boom poles are made. The lighter the better obviously. Also I am not sure it is the best purchase you can make....

Answer (score 1):

I absolutely agree that you should get a carbon fiber pole if at all possible.  They make a huge difference in your day to day work experience and are a downright pleasure to use.

I did a lot of research before I bought mine and ended up with a Gitzo six section pole and absolutely love it.  It is light, has really easy to use and positive feeling, super-strong section locks and it feels indestructible.  A quick check online shows that you can get a 4 section for under $200 (US).

Unless you absolutely have to have it, don't bother with internal cabling.  From what I hear from other users, the "convenience" is just never worth the extra price.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the difference is all in the locking-system of the sections as well as the thickness of the boom. The Micro looks REALLY unimpressive, though I haven't seen it live, of what I can tell from the pictures it looks like pretty hard to operate in the field.

Answer (score 0):

Don't buy a Rode boom pole. They're aluminium. If you're going to pick up dialog and swing it around set, you'll most likely be battling handling noise and heaviness. A cheap boom pole is expensive in the long run cus in a year you'll instantly be thinking of the next boom purchase.

Get a good, more expensive pole that lives forever and is lighter. Like the PSC, or K-tek.

It's worth it.

Comment: Probably should mention than I'm not willing to spend more than £200. Some of the prices of these glorified metallic sticks are insane. The KE89 looks as if it might be in my price range. Thanks for the tips.  

Comment: If you can't spend more than £200 then I see your dilemma. Personally, I'd wait til I had the proper money and get a great one instead of the "cheap in-between" one.They always end up costing more than what you payed.

Answer (score 0):

I've used them and reckon they are pretty crap. You could do better with a painting stick. Too thick, too heavy, and too long. I've got my eye on the [Lightwave A5](http://www.rycote.com/products/boom_pole/). The company's been taken over by Rycote so there should be reasonable amounts of QC there. More expensive than the Rode, but the little bit extra lets you put the pole in your luggage and not have to check it in as an additional odd ball package. It is made of aluminum though, and I haven't used it myself. Anyone like to chime in with experiences on this pole?

Comment: Used them, not extensively, but some... They're not in my favorite list either. Like the Rode, it's aluminium, which is bad right there, but unlike the Rode it doesn't have any fluffy stuff on it which makes your fingers freakishly cold on those days. The locking rings only go halfways and they're a pain to tighten. My 02

Comment: darn... there goes my cheap pole. hah

Comment: You will thank yourself in the long run (and your hands will too!) If you get a more expensive pole. But I mean it's all about what you need it for, right? If your only need is to have a pole to thread a mic to and record FX with you go with whatever you see fit, but I'd never get a cheap pole wanting to be able to use it for dialogue recording. And Rode and Lightwave (in my opinion) just doesn't cut it. 

Comment: @Tak I have the Lightwave A5 (coiled) and my experiences have generally been positive. The grip and twist locking system takes a bit of getting used to - make sure that you lock each section tightly or it'll come undone on it's own. But for an aluminium pole, it's pretty lightweight. Overall, I think it's good value for it's price range.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same situation i.e. saving up for a boom pole. I've decided to save up for a good spec boom pole, since it greatly enhances your ability to boom effectively and with less arm fatigue. I've used aluminium (Rode) and carbon fibre poles, and must say that your arms definitely appreciate you using carbon fibre! I'm saving up for a [Panamic Boom Pole](http://www.panamic.net/) which I've used and would recommend to anybody! :)